# Accessing a control of Gridview in Edit mode

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Gridview RowDataBound event I am reading in the controls with a direct cast as so...

```
Dim transTB As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Row.Cells(3).Controls(1), TextBox)
Dim engLabel As Label = DirectCast(e.Row.Cells(2).Controls(1), Label)
```

In the second column, cell 2, I added two more controls, another label and textbox, only in Edit mode.

```
Dim newTB6 As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Row.Cells(2).Controls(2), TextBox)
```

I am trying to get to the new textbox newTB6 with the above cast. I can not find it.

Here is the inline...

```
<EditItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# EncodeIT(Eval("shrt_Txt")) %>'></asp:Label><br /><br />
   <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text="Train"></asp:Label>
     <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Width="400px" Text='<%# Eval("lan_Strg") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Curious on how to find the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it...

```
Dim newTB6 As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Row.Cells(2).Controls(2).FindControl("Textbox6"), TextBox)
```